# Rails logger stuck at level 1 :info

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason, Rails is starting with `logger.level :info` and I am unable to change it anywhere.

`logger.level :debug` is ignored in initializers, application.rb or development.rb

The only thing that has worked is putting

```
Rails.logger.level = 0
```

in my auth filter in application_controller.rb which of course is undesired.

It doesn't seem to be an environment issue because it also happens when deployed to staging / production. It ignores `logger.level :debug` as well

May a gem be causing this? I have over 50 with no obvious candidates. Is there a way that I can monitor where the default Rails log level is being changed to :info?

I am using Rails 5.0.2, Ruby 2.3.1 and Puma